# Inserting error (or spacer) when IMPORTXML can't scrape data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml

I am using `IMPORTXML` to create what is essentially a vehicle inventory feed file.

My issue arises when a price is not included in our main website. What seemingly is happening is when the price is not included the `IMPORTXML` is skipping that one, not including any error or anything, and including the next price that it finds in its place on the sheet.

This is an issue since we are trying to line up these trucks with their vin, msrp, price, etc.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KceS3krlbpU2FjQly-tK8N5qiwshIq3rQFQ36WRNV5U/edit?usp=sharing

To give a specific example in my sheet this vin number: `1FTMF1E5XKKE62311` currently doesn't have a price listed on our site. Instead of inserting a blank cell or error, the `IMPORTXML` is inserting the price for the unit listed after this. This is creating a cluster of blank prices at the end of the sheet even though the prices for those vehicles are on our website. Basically this throws off the entire sheet after the first skipped price.

Here is how we are pulling in internet price currently:

```
=IFERROR({IMPORTXML(A4,"//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']");
 IMPORTXML(A5,"//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']");
 IMPORTXML(A6,"//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']");
 IMPORTXML(A7,"//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']");
 IMPORTXML(A8,"//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']");
 IMPORTXML(A9,"//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']");
 IMPORTXML(A10,"//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']");
 IMPORTXML(A11,"//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']")},"")
```

We were hoping that the error handler would work but unfortunately, it didn't. Does anyone have any thoughts on how we would not break the import order when there is a price that isn't listed?

Any advice would be much appreciated!!

*update* changed above sheet to be editable by anyone if you'd like to make a column and give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- to avoid array literal errors it should be:

```
=QUERY({
 IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A4,  "//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']"), "");
 IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A5,  "//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']"), "");
 IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A6,  "//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']"), "");
 IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A7,  "//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']"), "");
 IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A8,  "//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']"), "");
 IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A9,  "//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']"), "");
 IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A10, "//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']"), "");
 IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A11, "//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']"), "")}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

Comment: This might be a better formula than what I was initially using but still doesn't seem to skip or insert a placeholder when that path is invalid ie price doesn't exist (or at least I can't seem to get it to).

So essentially all the unknown prices are still bunching up at the bottom.

If it should and I am using it wrong, please let me know :)

Thanks for your help User0!

Comment: depends... if you know the exact amount of imported stuff you can change ending of each row from formula from `, "");` to: `, {"";"";""});` (eg if you know that it should scrape 3 cells under each other). this way it will be pre-fixed. also you will need to drop the query

Comment: I am always trying to import the exact same amount of data per row. Like in that example file, there are 4 items I would like to import (vehicle title, MSRP, VIN, and Price). Your example and my price column only attempt to import the price so not exactly sure what you mean when you say if I know that it should scrape 3 cells under each other.

Also not clear what you mean when you say that I will need to drop the query. Thanks User0!

Comment: try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhEb8.png

Comment: Hey User0, tried your suggestion here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KceS3krlbpU2FjQly-tK8N5qiwshIq3rQFQ36WRNV5U/edit?usp=sharing and it seemed to still not skip or insert a placeholder when internet price was not available. That vin currently in F4 (last 4 are 9816) ideally will be blank since it currently doesn't have a price available. It is instead still snagging the price for the next vehicle and putting it in the first cell in the column. Please let me know if I did anything wrong or if you have any other suggestions! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: imho I still not sure what are you after... you want to skip missing price like for example here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJJGi.png - so when price is missing then it will skip a row (?) so atm in your sheet the data/price is offset by one row?. can you point out specific examples?

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE({
 IFERROR(FILTER(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(A4, "//*"),8000,2),"select Col2 where (Col1='FINAL PRICE:' and Col2 is not null) or (Col2='Call For Price') limit 132", 0),MOD(ROW(A2:A111),2)=0),"")},
 "Call For Price", ))`

Comment: Yup! you got it exactly! So when the data is acquired, if there is a missing variable (in this case price like in your image) all of the data isn't thrown off by one cell. That is a really smart solution simply skipping a row when you detect another variable like Call For Price. I am trying to understand this formula a bit and am making progress, but still haven't been able to incorporate the 2nd url (in A5) so it gets data from both urls in A4 and A5. You have been super helpful User0.

Comment: Also, how are you getting the correct Xpath from this IMPORTXML(A4, "//*")? Sorry this is a more advanced Gsheets formula than I am used to working with so trying to learn a bit too :)

Comment: `"//*"` means "get everything" :D full source code. that's why it needs to be restricted with ARRAY_CONSTRAIN to output only 8000 rows of code in 2 columns and then QUERY filters out only fields that are needed

Comment: ahh ok I understand. Last question: How would I get the formula to handle multiple urls for instance on the test sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KceS3krlbpU2FjQly-tK8N5qiwshIq3rQFQ36WRNV5U/edit#gid=0 urls found in cells A4 AND A5? Thanks so much User0!

Comment: with semicolon - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMcxw.png

Comment: So it looks like your formula is stopping at row 113, with a vehicle price of $34,378. There should be more vehicles included and the price goes down to $20,427 on for the final vehicle of the second page (the A5 URL) Is this due to the output limit you have in place? Sorry for all the question, this is very much a learning experience.

Comment: it could be. try increasing 8000 or maybe add more empty rows at bottom

Answer (score 0):

**Edit : found a way to spot missing datas**

---

**Original answer :**
There are no errors because there's no data : `IMPORTXML` retrieve every data corresponding to a specific Xpath query and will not display anything if there's nothing.
Conclusion : `IFERROR` is useless here.
However what you can do is concatenate your IMPORTXML queries using `|` like this :

```
=IMPORTXML(A4,"//h2[@class='vehicleTitle margin-x']/a/span[@class='notranslate']")
=IMPORTXML(A4,"//div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']/ul/li/span[@style='text-decoration:line-through;'][@class='pull-right']")
etc....
```

Becomes

```
     =IMPORTXML(A4,"//h2[@class='vehicleTitle margin-x']/a/span[@class='notranslate'] |
 //div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']/ul/li/span[@style='text-decoration:line-through;'][@class='pull-right'] |
 //div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//li[@class='vinDisplay']/span | 
 //div[@class='col-xs-12 visible-xs margin-top-1x']//span[@style='font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;'][@class='pull-right primaryPrice']
")
```

Result is an array like this one :

```
2019 Ford F-150 XL
$30,045
$20,427
1FTMF1CB6KKC12430
2019 Ford F-150 XL
$30,045
$20,427
1FTMF1CB8KKC12381
2019 Ford F-150 XL
$31,450
$21,846
1FTMF1CBXKKD26088
...
  and then where there's no data for the price : 
...
2019 Ford F-150 XLT
$54,200
$39,758
1FTEW1E53KKC32677
2019 Ford F-150 XL    here's the vehicle 
1FTMF1E5XKKE62311     VIM but no price
2019 Ford F-150 XLT
$53,620
$39,853
1FTEW1E43KKD96874
```

Just need to find a solution to rearrange the data.

---

**Edit : Solution to rearrange the data.**

Next to the result column `B2:B`, I put this formula in `C2` then expand it `=countif(arrayformula(regexmatch(INDIRECT("B2:B"&ROW(B2)),"Ford")),true)`
It increments a counter for each new vehicule name with the keyword `Ford`.

[image: Counter for each new vehicule]

Then I used the same idea to create an array for each entry :

```
=transpose(FILTER($B$2:$B$401,$C$2:$C$401=row(A1)))
```

The final result when there's missing data :

[image: Array with the missing data]

Comment: Thanks so much for this suggestion Paul! It's definitely a different strategy I didn't consider. Experimenting now to see if I can figure out how to insert some type of placeholder text in the cell when I rearrange in place of where the price would normally import if present. If I find a solution I will post.

Comment: I think it's definitely a better strategy for one reason : you make less calls with `importxml` (max is 50/day AFAIK). I'll try to find a solution but right now I have no idea to how ths problem should be approached : maybe some `REGEX-PLACE-EXTRACT-??` formula ? or with apps-script ?

Comment: Hmm yea almost some kind of logic like after a cell containing "Ford" there has to be two cells with a dollar sign.

Comment: @BrianL I think I found a way if it's still relevant for you.

Comment: @paul sure I would love to see what you came up with! I found a hackey workaround that works in some instances but it is not at all an elegant solution.

Comment: I already updated my answer. It's a solution to rearrange the data and a way to look for missing prices. I don't know why but it just came to me yesterday for whatever reasons haha.  (EDIT : I just realized that what you were suggesting the 29 August was the way to go :o)